# Remove block from layout depends on condition

Tags: magento2, layout, addtocart

I want to remove  block **product.info.addtocart** from **layout** depends on some conditions

Comment: We need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifconfig` on block

```
<block class=“…” ifconfig=“section/group/field” name=“product.info.addtocart” />
```

Or you can use helper:

```
<block name="product.info.addtocart" class="...">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="helper" helper=“Vendorname\Modulename\Helper\Data::method”>
            <param name="name">Vendorname_Modulename::data/template.phtml</param>
        </argument>
    </action>
</block>
```

The result in both cases it must to be boolean.

If you want to use in other cases, we need more details.

Comment: With helper worked

Answer (score 3):

You can't remove block based on conditions in layout except system value(`ifconfig`) but you can do this from controller.

e.g)

```
if(here your condition)
{
   $layout = $this->getLayout();
   $layout->unsetElement('product.info.addtocart'); //block name
}
```

I hope it helps you.